# CAS + Spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, authorization, cas

I am new to spring security. My application is already using spring security to authenticate and authorize the user. Now i want to use the CAS authentication for the user to authenticate and the authorization to be done by my application only. I tried to configure my application by referring the below website:

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/Using+the+CAS+Client+3.1+with+Spring+Security

But every time my application ends up with not invoking the CAS filter and goes to the default  configured login page and not the CAS login page.
Is there any website or documentation by following it I will easily implement the CAS.

Comment: can you post your spring security application context config please? make sure to change any sensitive data tho!

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security documentation is good: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#cas